# IDENTITY INSERT ON/OFF on an entire database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a script that I need to run that has values that needs to be inserted everywhere there is null values in columns. for this to happen I need to set IDENTITY_INSERT OFF on the entire database. At the end of the script IDENTITY_INSERT needs to be switched on again. Is there a statement that can be used to set IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF over an entire datebase or is it only possible to do each table separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't totally clear what you want to do, but as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) says, only one table in a session can have `IDENTITY_INSERT` on, therefore you cannot disable it on all tables simultaneously. Your script will have to go table by table, setting it off, doing your inserts for that table only and then setting it on again.

Comment: That is what I had to do at the end of the day. Well atleast it is working. thnx

Answer (score 0):

On the Import/Export Wizard where it shows the list of tables, click the checkbox on the left size of the header so that the system selects all the tables.   Click Edit Mappings and you will have the chance to select Identity Insert for all selected tables.

Here's the link that saved me a bunch of time:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190119/how-to-set-enable-identity-insert-for-all-the-tables-at-once-during-importing